# Magento2 Data Migration Exception\LocalizedException

Tags: magento, magento2, mcrypt

i got an error after starting the data migration cli tool.
I cant find any imformation maybe someone already got that error and could help me.

> [Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException]
>    Key must not exceed 32 bytes.

I changed my encryption key but that dont fixed the error. 
Mcrypt is enabled and Magento is Up to date (2.1.4)
I want to migrate from 1.9.3.2 and i have already set up my configuration and mappings.

michael

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: ok, i will post it on magento.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

app/etc/env.php is populated with the details of your installation. Look at the contents crypt, and make sure that key doesn't have multiple lines appended to it, as was the case in my new installation, after running the setup:install multiple times.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I cut the old encrypt key to 32 signs and i updated the informations in env.php ( i also cut the new encrypt key to 32 signs ). My old encrypt key contains 52 signs but only the first 32 digits were used.